# Print distinct characters and print stars in next rows that number of characters are repeated

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a string `$string = "CONSTANTMAINONE";`

I want to print distinct characters and print stars in next rows that number of characters are repeated.

```
C   O   N   S   T   A   M   I   E
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
    *   *       *   *           
        *                  
        *
```

What I had tried

> Loop the characters
>   Add the character as a key and count as a value
>   Then printed, but that output is not coming vertically and the question should be do not use `table` or `pre` tags

```
$string = "CONSTANTMAINONE";
$repeated_char = [];
for($i=0; $i<=strlen($string);$i++){
  if(!array_key_exists($string[$i], $repeated_char)){
     $repeated_char[$string[$i]] = 1;
  }else{
     $repeated_char[$string[$i]] += 1;
  }
}
```

So far, output is

```
C => 1
o => 1
N => 4
s => 1
T => 1
..etc..,
```

Then, printing the characters

```
foreach($repeated_char as $key=>$val){
  echo $key. "&nbsp;";
  for($j=0; $j<$val; $j++){
    echo "*";
  }  
   echo "<br/>";
}
```

So, the final output from my code

```
C *
o **
N ****
S *
T **
A **
M *
I *
E *
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, I have tried something..will update the question.. :)

Comment: Updated the question..please check it.

Comment: You wrote you want distinct characters but you have 2 times T in your example output?!

Comment: Yes Rizier, you are correct..I have updated. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This answer is form the first revision:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28536477/1

This should work for you:

(Here i use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to create a array out of the string. After this i count all array values with [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). Then it's just a simple printing thing. First i print all unique values and after this i print the starts and decrement the value in a tmp array)

```
<?php

    $string = "CONSTANTMAINONE";
    $array = str_split($string);
    $count = array_count_values($array);
    $tmp = $count;

    echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
        foreach($count as $k => $v)
            echo "<td>" . $k . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";

        for($i = 0; $i < max($count); $i++) {
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach($tmp as $k => $v) {
                if($v >= 1)
                    echo "<td>*</td>";
                else
                    echo "<td></td>";
                $tmp[$k]--;
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

Output:

```
C   O   N   S   T   A   M   I   E
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
    *   *       *   *       
        *
```

Comment: Some characters are coming one more time extra..for eg: 'C' should be 1 'O' should be '2'

Comment: Also, is it possible to print as it is without table ?

Comment: Changing the condition if($v >= 0) to if($v >= 1) is fix the problem..please change it

Comment: @Asik Changed it, without the table it's very hard